# How do I access GUI (GTK) from multi threads?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have a worker thread spawned from a GUI (for GUI performance), how do I access GUI, such as spawning new windows/widgets from the thread itself?

I tried using delegates but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas? Possibly examples? Thank you.

Comment: Delegates don't work!? Do you use Control.BeginInvoke() method to invoke delegates?

Comment: I didn't, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Please keep in mind he is using GTK, not Windows Forms, so the API is different (see below).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to their [Best Practices](http://www.mono-project.com/Best_Practices):

> Gtk# is not a thread-safe toolkit, which means that only one thread at a time can safely invoke methods on Gtk#. This thread is typically the thread executing the main loop (which is when control has been explicitly transfered to Gtk).
>
> When application developers need to have threads update some element of the graphical user interface they have to either acquire a lock that allows them to issue Gtk# toolkit invocations or they can make their code execute on the same thread as the one thread that executes the main loop.
>
> To invoke a method on the GTK+ main loop thread and avoid any threading problems with GTK, you can use the Gtk.Application.Invoke() method (if you are targetting Gtk# 1.0 you can use Gtk.ThreadNotify).

The following example is provided; you should use `Invoke` to execute any Gtk code from within the main loop:

```
public void ThreadedMethod()
{
    Gtk.Application.Invoke(delegate {
        do_stuff_in_main_thread();
    });
}
```

Comment: How to do the same thing in gtkmm?

Comment: How can handle function return value using Gtk.Application.Invoke?